# After Effects import SVG

Tags: svg, animation, adobe-after-effects

I tried to import an SVG into After Effects but got an error stating that file format is not supported. Is there any way I can achieve this or is there any alternative solutions?

Comment: maybe you could go with copy paste; that sometimes works i similar situations for me

Answer (score 2):

SVG [isn't a supported image format](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/kb/supported-file-formats-effects-cs4.html#mainSupportedstillimagefileformats), so there's not a whole lot you can do other than convert to a supported format. As long as you have access to Illustrator then the easiest option is to simply open and re-save as an .ai file. That will obviously retain the vector data so you can animate paths etc. If you don't have access to Illustrator and need to import it as a vector then you could try converting to another vector capable format such as PDF or EPS.

If you only need a still image then you could simply rasterize to e.g. a PNG, just make sure you rasterize the image large enough for your needs.

There *may* also be a third-party script or plugin that will import SVG for you. I couldn't find any but there are scripts that will *export* SVG, so it's a possibility.

Comment: Illustrator or any vector editing software, they can also use an online tool [such as this](http://svgtopng.com/)  to convert SVG to PNG.

Comment: @WELZ depends on what the other vector editing software outputs; if it only outputs SVG then it's no good! :)

Comment: Inkscape for example (as a freeware)